# Recognizing anonymous events in logs

Tags: solidity, events, logs

Is there any way to recognize if a log contains an anonymous topic? From what I can tell is that anonymous events are represented in a log without the signature on the first index. Giving the option to include 4 instead of 3 topics. That would be a way to recognize them, however what if an anonymous event generates a log with less than 4 topics?

I need to find a couple of logs with anonymous events so that I can study them.

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous topic"?

Comment: As explained in ethers.js "https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/#events-solidity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a non-anonymous event, `topics[0]` will be the signature of the event name. In an anonymous event, the signature of the event name is **not** a topic.

If you have access to the ABI or the source code of the contract, here is what you could do:

1. Find the [signature hash of the event name](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0-rc.0/web3-eth-abi.html?highlight=signature#encodeeventsignature).
2. Check if `topics[0]` is equal to this signature. If not, you have an anonymous event.

If you don't have access to the ABI or the source code, I don't think that it is possible because there is no way to know if `topics[0]` is the event name signature or a `bytes32` indexed argument.

On a side-note, the JSON ABI would indicate if an event is anonymous ([see the docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/abi-spec.html?highlight=anonymous#json)).

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly. A log can therefore always have a max of 4 topics. When the event is anonymous it has a max of 4 topics. When the event isn't anonymous it has a signature on `topic[0]` and 3 topics. Only if I have the ABI, I can say for sure that the signature is on `topic[0]`.

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. Unless someone can think of another way...